# How to translate SQL to LINQ?

Tags: linq

### sql

```
select * from (select * from tabla limit 1) as a inner join table b on a.id = b.id where a.id = id
```

### LINQ

```
from s in tableA
join c in (from a in tableB where a.id==id select a).FirstOrDefault() on s.id equals c.id
where s.id == id
select s
```

I want to translate this sql to linq but failed. How can I do translate?

Comment: What is "tableA" in your LINQ example? Is it the table name or is it an EF object? What do you mean it "failed"? What is the error message? Are you using Entity Framework at all (or some other object relational mapping, ORM)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it, but you should check what sql is being generated by linq.

```
a = tableA.FirstOrDefault();

//First option
tableB.Where(xb => xb.id = a.id)
      .Select(xb => new {a = a, b = xb})
      .Where(abx => abx.a.id == id)

//Second option
tableB.Select(xb => new {a = a, b = xb})
      .Where(abx => abx.a.id == id && abx.a.id = abx.b.id)
```